# Show data by grouping values in a column

Tags: group-by, powerbi, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop

I'm working on a PowerBI project to analyze some alarm log data generated by one of our applications. For sake of brevity, this is what a typical log would look like if you get rid of all clutter.

```
TimeStamp,Unit,Alarm,Machine
2020/02/25 13:33:45,A,Error,M1
2020/02/25 13:33:46,B,Error,M1
2020/02/25 13:33:47,C,Serious Error,M2
2020/02/25 13:33:48,A,Warning,M4
2020/02/25 13:33:49,C,Information,M3
2020/02/25 13:33:50,B,Information,M1
2020/02/25 13:33:51,D,Warning,M1
2020/02/25 13:33:52,E,Error,M2
2020/02/25 13:33:53,A,Serious Error,M4
2020/02/25 13:33:54,C,Dead Serious Error,M5
2020/02/25 13:33:55,B,Serious Error,M2
2020/02/25 13:33:56,B,Warning,M1
2020/02/25 13:33:57,D,Information,M3
2020/02/25 13:33:58,A,Warning,M2
2020/02/25 13:33:59,C,Error,M1
2020/02/25 13:34:00,E,Error,M2
2020/02/25 13:34:01,C,Critical Error,M4
2020/02/25 13:34:02,A,Critical Error,M5
2020/02/25 13:34:03,B,Error,M4
2020/02/25 13:34:04,C,Warning,M2
```

In the designer, if I want to show alarms by count, I can simply create a column chart with `Axis = Alarm` and `Value = Count of Alarm`, which would give me the following.

[image]

Which is absolutely fine.
But what if I want to generate a similar chart, but alarms grouped by the alarm text. For example, suppose these are my groups.

> Errors - Any alarm that contains the word 'error'.
>
> Warnings - Any alarm that contains the word 'warning'.
>
> Other - Everything else.

This would mean the above log would be grouped into 3 categories, and it should look like this.

[image]

I generated the above by manually creating another log file, which I don't want to do in my real project. How would I go about achieving this?

I know the `GroupBy` function exists in the Query Editor, but it doesn't seem to give me the results I need.

---

### Edit

Note that in my real log there are hundreds (if not thousands) of different alarms, and I may also get daily logs from different places where each new log may potentially contain an alarm that wasn't there before. Unfortunately I don't have a full list of alarms across the board, so creating a static table with alarms grouped isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a calculated column either in the query editor or using DAX to group these and then use that calculated column instead of `Alarm` for your axis.

Here's an example of how you could do it with DAX:

```
Group =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Table'[Alarm], "Error" ), "Errors",
    CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Table'[Alarm], "Warning" ), "Warnings",
    "Other"
)
```

This `SWITCH` returns the value for the first line that equals `TRUE()`. More details on this here:

[DAX – The Diabolical Genius of “SWITCH TRUE”](https://powerpivotpro.com/2015/03/the-diabolical-genius-of-switch-true/)

---

You also can do it with a custom column in the query editor using M code like this:

```
if Text.Contains([Alarm], "Error") then "Errors"
else if Text.Contains([Alarm], "Warning") then "Warnings"
else "Other"
```

---

Note: M code is case-sensitive whereas DAX is not.

Comment: Oh wow I did not know about the `switch` in DAX but this looks elegant. Thanks!

Comment: And cool article linked there, that's definitely informative. Thanks!